# Tippy js, how to hide tooltip when mouse hovers over it

Tags: tippyjs

I have a tippy that programmatically appears but I want to have disappear if the user hovers their mouse over it or over the element that it is attached to.

More specifically, I want it in such a way that when a user hovers the mouse over the tooltip, the tooltip hides but on mouseout of the area that the tooltip was it reappears.